# Who do I talk to to get a bad Tag fixed?

Tags: support, status-completed, retagging

The [highlader-franchise](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/highlader-franchise) tag is misspelled. It should be spelled [highlander-franchise](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/highlander-franchise). Someone forgot the 'n' in highlander.

Comment: But now where will I go to ask questions about getting my ladder heightened?!

Comment: **There can only be one** ("n" in the tag).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Done.

Comment: That was quick, thanks Kevin.

Comment: Ah, but who do I speak to about getting it un-fixed to annoy Morgan?